# tqdm Nested Loops not functioning properly?

Tags: python, nested-loops, tqdm

I am currently trying to implement tqdm on a process in some data analysis code I am writing to visualize the process better, however I am running into a problem where tqdm will raise the desc input I've given and the time and it/s value, but not the actual progress bar. Even though I call it in other functions and it works properly.

The code in question:

```
 for j, array in tqdm(enumerate(avgd_waves),
                         desc="Check for nan Values"):
        for k, point in tqdm(enumerate(array),
                             desc="Read Individual Array",
                             leave=False):
            if np.isnan(point) == True:
                avgd_waves[j][k] = 0
```

The output:

`Check for nan Values: 44it [00:39,  1.10it/s]`

****edit*****
the output I actually want should contain a progress bar like this:

`Check for nan Values: 100%|██████████████████████| 44/44 [01:14<00:00,  1.70s/it]`

It will display the second loops progression the same as the first. The desc value along with the values on the end, but not the actual bar? Any help would be appreciated.

I'm not sure where to go to fix this as I'm still pretty new to coding and reading documentation is alittle challenging for me. I looked through more parameter options and couldn't find anything on actually disabling the code. I added a time.sleep(0.001) into both loops to see if maybe it was just to fast, but that didn't work.

Comment: It's unclear what output you're actually getting.  Do you actually see the `Read Individual Array` output message?

Comment: Perhaps it's because of `leave=False` in the inner loop?

Comment: Is part of the issue that you seek the display when the length in known (progress bar) rather than when the length is not known (iteration count)?

Comment: @JonSG youre right just got it running, it wasn't able to display a br since it didn't know it's total. just had to give it one

Answer (score 0):

Is part of the issue related to using an iterator via `enumerate()`?

This seems to work ok for me:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i, i_v in tqdm(list(enumerate(range(10))), desc="i", leave=False):
    for j, j_v in tqdm(list(enumerate(range(100))), desc="j", leave=False):
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: thanks for the response you posted right as I figured it out! I think the enumerate definitely confused it, but passing it a total parameter fixes the issue and a progressbar is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the tqdm function in this case couldn't tell what the total was an therefore couldn't display the progress bar. by adding a total parameter it was able to display the bar:

```
for j, array in tqdm(enumerate(avgd_waves),
                     desc="Check for nan Values"
                     , total=len(avgd_waves)):
    #the second loop loops through the individual values in each array
    for k, point in tqdm(enumerate(array),
                         desc="Read Individual Array",
                         leave=False,
                         total=len(array)):
```

this fixed the output to actually display the bar

```
Check for nan Values: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 44/44 [01:14<00:00,  1.70s/it]
```